# How Can I Add One More Language Programmatically

Tags: android

I want to add one more language to my app. I created 2nd string file, my Values file like that:

```
..
values
  -strings
     -strings.xml
     -strings.xml(fr)
```

If phone's local language is English, my app's display language is English or
If phone's local language is French, my app's display language is French. That's okay. But I want to add 2 button like English-French and I want to user sets app's language. How can I do that?

I tried this code but I must recreate the Activity and I can't get display language code for control user selection on Login Activity.

```
Locale locale = new Locale("fr");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
finish();
startActivity(getIntent());
```

Comment: Do you want to force one of locales already defined in strings.xml or add locale dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, you just have to update your views, you don't need to re-create your activity. When I did that, I used SharedPreference to get a little help, you'll need to invalidate all your views that you want to translate tho.

```
@Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String s) {
        if (s.equals(getString(R.string.languages_preference))){
            String langOptions = sharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.languages_preference), "");
            if (!langOptions.isEmpty()){
                setLocale(langOptions);
                this.invalidateOptionsMenu(); //change language of options mnus
                updateView();
            }
        }
    }

    private void updateView(){
            photoTitleLabel.setText(getString(R.string.photo_title));
            photoTitleLabel.invalidate();
            photoDescriptionLabel.setText(getString(R.string.photo_description));
            photoDescriptionLabel.invalidate();
            photoOwnerUsernameLabel.setText(getString(R.string.owner_username));
            photoOwnerUsernameLabel.invalidate();
            photoOwnerRealnameLabel.setText(getString(R.string.owner_realname));
            photoOwnerRealnameLabel.invalidate();
            photoDateTakenLabel.setText(getString(R.string.photo_taken_date));
            photoDateTakenLabel.invalidate();
            photoDatePostedLabel.setText(getString(R.string.photo_post_date));
            photoDatePostedLabel.invalidate();
            photoDateLastUpdateLabel.setText(getString(R.string.photo_update_date));
            photoDateLastUpdateLabel.invalidate();
            btnPreviousText.setText(getString(R.string.previous_photo));
            btnPreviousText.invalidate();
            btnNextText.setText(getString(R.string.next_photo));
            btnNextText.invalidate();
            photoLocationLabel.setText(R.string.photo_location);
            photoLocationLabel.invalidate();



    }
```

And this is my framgent settings that use SharedPreferences if that matter

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{

    private ListPreference listPreference;
    private PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen;

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);



    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String s) {
        if (s.equals(getString(R.string.languages_preference))){
            String langOptions = sharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.languages_preference), "");
            if (!langOptions.isEmpty()){
                setLocale(langOptions);
                listPreference = (ListPreference) findPreference(getString(R.string.languages_preference));
                PreferenceCategory preferenceCategory = (PreferenceCategory) findPreference("preferences");
                listPreference.setEntries(R.array.lang_opt);
                listPreference.setEntryValues(R.array.lang_values);
                listPreference.setTitle(getString(R.string.pref_language_title));
                preferenceCategory.setTitle(R.string.preferences);

            }
        }
    }

    public void setLocale(String lang) {
        Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang);
        Resources res = getResources();
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        conf.locale = myLocale;
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);

        /**/
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
        sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you have to call  `invalidate();` for every single view ?

Comment: as you said, the solution works, but you recreate the activity. What's happening is your view is already created and because of this your language selected is not reflecting on your texts, so you have to call invalidate() to re-create those views or re-create the activity, it's up to you

Comment: please note, it's not my question, i'm simply viewing your answer :) so i am asking you purely, why do you have to call invalidate, does it not work by just setting the string resources ?

Comment: oh I'm sorry @a_local_nobody, didn't saw that. Changing the Locale will change the string resources that your app is using as well, but the activity created already keeps the same, so either you re-create your this activity or you invalidate your TextViews. All other acitivitys created afterwards will be ok tho. Maybe there is a better solution, I didn't found anything else easier a while ago when I was working on this code

Comment: was just interested, i've never used invalidate before and i thought that just changing the strings would be enough, was just wondering :)

Comment: Yeah, it's kinda weird, just used once and never more

Comment: I can write right now, that's the solution. Thank you @Shermano

Answer (score 0):

**There is no way to add new language as** `stringfile.xml` **into [value] package Programmatically.**

But you can use some another solutions to use new languages into your project:

**1- Create locale database:**

Create locale database contain all strings you want, create a table contain 4 columns:

- **id** (55)
- **key** (user_name)
- **value** (User Name)
- **locale** (fr)

and it is easy to get any value by the key according the locale what you want, and you can add, edit or delete any Language or String from your Database.

**2- You can use Google Translate API**

Check this link please to see [How use Google Translate API in Android projects](https://medium.com/@yeksancansu/how-to-use-google-translate-api-in-android-studio-projects-7f09cae320c7).

**Note:**
These ways or any another way will add more logic in your code, so if there is any way to add all stings files into your res project it is better.

Answer (score 0):

*Please, Consider the method below as an another way of handling a specific case of this issu:*

If the number of items to be translated is not so much, you can handle this issue using `SharedPreferences`.
This way; you have to define a `itemSharedPreference` for each item and a `languageSharedPreference` for each language.
When the language is changed, in fact the value of `languageSharedPreference` is changed; The text of translatable items are modified via the condition set for them according to the value of `itemSharedPreference`.